# lstm with variable batch_size

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

we know ,during training,we need to feed_dict a batch_size data.However,in the last epoch, the number of data is less than a batch size.how could i do? i try to use variable batch_size,but i meet some problems when i use rnn. the code is below:

```
input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, num_steps])

with tf.variable_scope('forward'):

    cellL = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_size, forget_bias=1.0)
    state_init_L = tf.get_variable("init_L",initializer=cellL.zero_state(tf.shape(input_data)[0],tf.float32))
```

error is

> ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified:
>   Tensor("model/init_variable_L/zeros:0", shape=(?, 100), dtype=float32,
>   device=/device:GPU:0)

thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to always produce batches of fixed size.

You can drop last few training examples.
Or you can repeat the last example multiple times to fill the batch.
When you have enough data, a few missing or repeated examples do not matter.

Comment: During test you can do the same thing. If the last batch is incomplete, repeat the last example multiple times to fill the batch. Then make sure you only count it once when computing accuracy (or whatever test metrics you have).

Comment: I There are other ways, such as creating a different graph for eval with batch size=1 , and sharing LSTM with the training graph. But padding the batch is probably the easiest solution

Comment: thanks.and i want to ask whether there are some problems i can fix my code above